# Use of "this" operator in Java

Tags: java

Is there any other use of `this` keyword other than accessing member variable having the same name as local variable

`this.x = x`

Is there any other situation where it make sense to use this keyword.

Comment: FYI, `this` is a keyword, not an operator.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One other use of `this` keyword is in constructor chaining, for example:

```
class Person {

    private String name;
    private int age;

    public Person() {
        //Invoking another constructor
        this("John", 35);
    }

    public Person(String name, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much. This is something new i learnt today and this is what i was looking for.

Answer (score 6):

You can pass the current object as a parameter to another method.

Answer (score 4):

Below points have been taken from [Java docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html)

1. The most common reason for using the `this` keyword is because a field is shadowed by a method or constructor parameter.
2. From within a constructor, you can also use the `this` keyword to call another constructor in the same class.

Answer (score 3):

`this` represents  the current instance inside the instance.

It is useful for:

- identifying instance variables from locals (including parameters)
- it can be used by itself to simply refer to member variables and methods, invoke other constructor overloads.
- refer to the *instance*.

Some examples of applicable uses (not exhaustive):

```
class myClass
{
     private int myVar; 

     public myClass() {
          this(42); // invoke parameterized constructor of current instance
     }

     public myClass(int myVar) {
         this.myVar = myVar; // disambiguate 
     }

     public void another() {
          this.second(); // used "just because"
     }

     private void second() {
          System.out.println("whatever");
     }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can reference a field or call a method of an enclosing class

```
public class Examples {
    public class ExamplesInner {
        private int x;
        public ExamplesInner() {
            x = 3; // refers to ExamplesInner.x
            Examples.this.x = 3; // refers to Examples.x
        }
    }

    private int x;
}
```

[For full usage, read the java language specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8.3)

> The keyword this may be used only in the body of an instance method,
>   instance initializer, or constructor, or in the initializer of an
>   instance variable of a class. If it appears anywhere else, a
>   compile-time error occurs.
>
> When used as a primary expression, the keyword this denotes a value
>   that is a reference to the object for which the instance method was
>   invoked (§15.12), or to the object being constructed.
>
> The type of this is the class C within which the keyword this occurs.
>
> At run time, the class of the actual object referred to may be the
>   class C or any subclass of C.
>
> The keyword this is also used in a special explicit constructor
>   invocation statement, which can appear at the beginning of a
>   constructor body (§8.8.7).

Comment: Wouldn't `x` be in scope here anyway? Maybe you meant to make it a shadowed field?

Comment: @DaoWen It's usually done implicitly by the constructor. But it would reveal shadowed fields in that case.

Answer (score 2):

- this keyword can be used to refer current class instance variable.
- this() can be used to invoke current class constructor.
- this keyword
  can be used to invoke current class method (implicitly)
- this can be
  passed as an argument in the method call.
- this can be passed as
  argument in the constructor call.
- this keyword can also be used to
  return the current class instance.

find examples from this:
http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2012/01/this-keyword-java-example-tutorial.html

Answer (score 0):

The `this` operator is used as reference to currently executing object. It is concerned with objects, and hence cannot be and should not be used with static references, where classes are used instead of objects.

The `this` operator can be used to invoke the constructor like `this()`

The `this` operator also avoids naming ambiguities and can be used to pass the current object as reference to functions

Answer (score 0):

`this` lets you disambiguate between the private member `foo` and the parameter `foo` passed into the `constructor`: EX

```
 class bar
 {
     private int foo;
     public Foo(int foo)
     {
        this.foo =foo;
     }
 }
```